# Errors in Console when using Google Maps: Uncaught ReferenceError: icon is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, maps

I've been trying to follow the tutorial from Google to implement Google Maps with MySQL and PHP. Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="map">

  </div>
</div>
<script>
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(XX.XXX, XX.XXX),
      zoom: 12
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
      downloadUrl('http://xxxxxx.com/xxxxxxxx.php/', function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
          var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');

          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

          var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
          var strong = document.createElement('strong');
          strong.textContent = id
          infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
          infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label
          });
          marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        });
      });
    }



  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
      }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
  }

  function doNothing() {}
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

I've successfully followed the tutorial through the point of creating a PHP script that creates the XML data and I call that data in the downloadUrl function. But, the tutorial is based on using a static XML file. I think there is something that I need to change to get the markers to appear on the map. When I open the console on my page, Im getting the following errors:

Uncaught ReferenceError: icon is not defined

at profile.php:57

at HTMLCollection.forEach ()

at profile.php:41

at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (profile.php:77)

Any ideas on how to solve these errors? I've been stuck on this for hours. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `icon` variable is not defined (while it is in the Google example you started with)

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't define `icon`.  Change:

```
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: point,
    label: icon.label
  });
```

To:

```
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: point
  });
```